# Copy a row in excel if the col matches a specific criteria into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to excel and have been looking at many functions to try to make use of some data I collected.

I have collected 2~3 data sets (index 0~2) every 5 mins. For example...

id  date            index   time
**1 1/1/2014 0:00       0   24

2   1/1/2014 0:00       1   25

3   1/1/2014 0:00       2   25**
4   12/31/2013 23:50    0   24
5   12/31/2013 23:50    1   25
**6 12/31/2013 23:45    0   24

7   12/31/2013 23:45    1   24

8   12/31/2013 23:45    2   25**
........

I want to copy a whole row that has the minimum time(col_4) value for each time. (also those with tie values). As a reult...

id  date        index   time
**1 1/1/2014 0:00       0   24**

4   12/31/2013 23:50    0   24
**6 12/31/2013 23:45    0   24

7   12/31/2013 23:45    1   24**

I have been looking at functions like min, Vlookup, choose, index,... I am also lookin on how to do vba. I have partially done some things but can't complete it. Any hints or comments would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what triggers the group change .... is it **index**  or **date/time** -  then your result should show ID's 1, 4, 6 ... i.e. what makes the group change between 7 & 8 ?

Comment: I'm sorry... I wrote the wrong results. I edited the results. group change trigger can either be by index or date/time. I collected data every 5 mins and some had 3(idx0~2) and some had 2(idx0~1) values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(column label "ID" in cell A1)

The underlying rule seems to be:

"A record is first-of-group if its time (last column) is smaller than the time of the previous record."

How you implement this rule depends on the degree of automation you want to apply. A formula-only approach could look like this:

- create one extra column E, column header in E1 is "Rank"
- starting with E2, enter formula `=IF(D2<D1,1,E1+1)` and copy down
- do an autofilter and filter for "Rank" = 1 to display the first-of-group record

(meaning that when the first-of-group condition is met, the rank is set to 1, else it's incremented ... advantage being you also have an information of how many records you have in a group by looking at the group maximum)

In a VBA script I'd implement this rule like this ...

```
Sub FindFirstOfGroup()
Dim SrcRange As Range, Idx As Long

    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.[A1]
    Idx = 2

    Do While SrcRange(Idx, 1) <> ""                        ' exit condition - first row with no ID
        If SrcRange(Idx, 4) < SrcRange(Idx - 1, 4) Then    ' group condition
            ' first-of-group found
            ' Debug.Print SrcRange(Idx, 1)                  ' do whatever needs to be done
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Alternatively you probably may want to use the rule

"A record is first-of-group if its index is 0."

Comment: Wow. thanks. Your idea gave me some idea to use the function I learned, however, not working properly. I am thinking of ranking tie values also and the time is not always in decending order. I have managed to use ={MIN(IF(B2=B:B,D:D))} to get the min time of each group by date (also by using curly brackets over MIN). I used it with =IF(E2={MIN(IF(B2=B:B,D:D))}, 1, E1+1) to rank the smallest tie values to 1 and others +1. But I guess the curly brakets in the IF statement is not working.